# Hovering div causes laggs

Tags: html, css

I want to hover a div. When i go with my mouse into the div ist lagging. The Content is not appearing clearly. Here´s my html and my css

```css
.unshow-txt:hover,
.unshow-txt:focus,
.unshow-txt:active {
  display: none;
}

.show-txt {
  display: none;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.box:hover .show-txt,
.box:focus .show-txt,
.box:active .show-txt {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="unshow-txt">
    <div class="middle">
      <div class="circle-o">
        <i class="fa fa-eye fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
    <h2 class="h2-bigger text-center">Vorausschauend</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="show-txt">
    <p>Some text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest to use the hover effect in the .box div. the bug is happening because you have a hover animation in the parent and the child

```css
.box:hover .unshow-txt,
.box:hover .unshow-txt,
.box:hover .unshow-txt {
  display: none;
}

.show-txt {
  display: none;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.box:hover .show-txt,
.box:focus .show-txt,
.box:active .show-txt {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="unshow-txt">
    <div class="middle">
      <div class="circle-o">
        <i class="fa fa-eye fa-3x" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
    <h2 class="h2-bigger text-center">Vorausschauend</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="show-txt">
    <p>Some text</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You want this ? [See this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/19re9xb8/2/)

I use siblings CSS selector to show the text :

```
.unshow-txt:hover ~ .show-txt,
.unshow-txt:focus ~ .show-txt,
.unshow-txt:active ~ .show-txt {
  display: inline;
}
```